# How do I control the number of textboxes displayed in a listbox based on the state of a checkbox using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I am collecting messages from a com port. When the message is received a time stamp is recorded. I then display the time stamp followed by the message. It looks like:

```
01/02/2022 13:14:15.123  00 48 B4 68 33
```

I want to add a checkbox that will show the timestamp when checked, and just the message when unchecked.

My XAML for displaying the timestamp and message:

```
        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MessageList" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SDIMessages}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecivedTime, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

My code for the checkbox

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding ShowTimeStamp, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Display Time Stamp"/>
```

Currently I have the binding for `ShowTimeStamp` working correctly. How do I hide the `TimeRecived`? I am still learning C#, XAML and MVVM. I believe I need to use a datatrigger somehow but how do I make the trigger from the checkbox affect a listbox?

Comment: You can binding "Opacity" of ReceiveTime to "IsChecked" of check box:
 Opacity="{Binding ElementName=checkbox, Path=IsChecked}"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can give checkbox a name ("CheckTimeStamp") and bind TextBlocks Visibility directly to IsChecked property (without involving view model) using BooleanToVisibilityConverter:

```
<CheckBox Grid.Row="0" Name="CheckTimeStamp" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="10,0,0,0" IsChecked="{Binding ShowTimeStamp, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="Display Time Stamp"/>

<ListBox Grid.Row="1" x:Name="MessageList" Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SDIMessages}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="boolToVisibility"/>
    </ListBox.Resources>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding RecivedTime, StringFormat=dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss.fff}" 
                           Visibility="{Binding ElementName=CheckTimeStamp, Path=IsChecked, Converter={StaticResource boolToVisibility}}"/>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Message}" Margin="10,0,0,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```